# What is the Difference between VLC Streaming Server and The VLC Media Player?

Tags: video-streaming, media-player, media, vlc

Can anyone please let me know the exact difference between the VLC media player and the VLC media server?

Also I wanted to install the VLC media server on my centos server. I tried to get some references on it but I did not find any tutorials or references on the same. If anyone have any idea, Please share the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **VLC media player** - can be used as a server and as a client to stream and receive network streams. VLC is able to stream all that it can read.
>
> **VLS (VideoLAN Server)** - can stream MPEG-1, MPEG-2 and MPEG-4 files, DVDs, digital satellite channels, digital terrestial television channels and live videos on the network in unicast or multicast. Most of the VLS functionality can now be found in VLC.

Finally:

> **Usage of VLC instead of VLS is advised**

You can use VLC directly from the command line so it's also suitable for a server environment.

Source: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html

Centos: http://www.unixmen.com/install-vlc-centos-7/